# Using $\|x\|$, what constant can lower bound $\|\Lambda^{-1}x\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-transformations

This is a pure algebraic question. Using a norm of the vector $\|x\|$, can I lower bound the  $\|\Lambda^{-1}x\|$? Note that $\Lambda$ satisfies the decomposition of a positive definite matrix $P=\Lambda^\top \Lambda$.
Though I can upper bound like $\|\Lambda^{-1}x\|<\|\Lambda^{-1}\|\|x\|$, I have no idea how lower bound...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there's something you neglected to mention, all we know about $\Lambda$ is that it is an invertible $n \times n$ (presumably real) matrix. Since $x = \Lambda \Lambda^{-1} x$, we have $\|x\| \le \|\Lambda\| \|\Lambda^{-1} x\|$, i.e.
$$ \|\Lambda^{-1} x\| \ge \|\Lambda\|^{-1} \|x\|$$

Comment: Very simple but essential! Thank you :)